# incompatible pointer types passing 'size_t *' (aka 'unsigned long *') to parameter of type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: c, size-t

I'm making a movie rating management program. I declared size_t as a data type to count, but I get this error. What's wrong with you?

```
int main(){
    struct movie movie_list[LMAX];
    size_t n_items = 0;

    read_file(movie_list, &n_items);
```

```
void read_file(struct movie movie_list[], int *ptr_n_items){ 

    for (int n = 0; n < num; ++n){
        if (fscanf(file, "%[^\n]%*c", movie_list[*ptr_n_items].title) != 1 || fscanf(file, "%f%*c", &movie_list[*ptr_n_items].rating) != 1){
            printf("ERROR: Wrong file format.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        *ptr_n_items += 1;
    }

    assert(*ptr_n_items == num);
```

I don't know how to solve the error. Tell me how.

Comment: `size_t` and `int` are different types (on 64-bit, size_t is usually twice as large). Change the type of the argument or of the variable to match.

Comment: When counting the number of C arrays, Lecture recommended using size_t. Then what should I use instead?

Comment: @myistocome What do you mean by _"instead"_? Why not use the recommended type?

Comment: Why not change ptr_n_items to `size_t *`?

Comment: Teacher recommended using size_t when counting the number of arrays in code. But there was an error using size_t. Of course, there is no error if you change it to int. So is there anything that can be used to count the number of arrays, like size_t?

Comment: change size_t n_items -> size_t *n_items?

Comment: There is an error because that function expects a `int*`. Why don't you make that a `size_t*` if your teacher suggests to use `size_t`?

Comment: Good job on checking the return of `fscanf ()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you supply a `size_t*` to a function which expects an `int*`. You need to do **one** of these:

- Change `size_t n_items = 0;` to

  ```c
  int n_items = 0;
  ```
- Change the function to

  ```c
  void read_file(struct movie movie_list[], size_t *ptr_n_items)
  ```

The teacher's recommendation was to use `size_t`s, so I suggest the second of the changes above.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t n_items = 0;

read_file(movie_list, &n_items);
```

`read_file()` is passed a pointer to `size_t`, or `size_t *`, but it expects a pointer to `int`, or `int *`.

Either change the type of `n_items` to `int` (not recommended):

```
// size_t n_items = 0;
int n_items = 0;
```

Or change `read_file()`'s second parameter to accept a `size_t *`:

```
// void read_file(struct movie movie_list[], int *ptr_n_items)
void read_file(struct movie movie_list[], size_t *ptr_n_items)
```